# Interface Builder Latest Xcode does not point to latest version

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode10.1

In Xcode 10.1, when I open a newly created storyboard I see

[image: Storyboard properties]

I have the option to specify Xcode 10. But even when I set it, it jumps back to Xcode 9 after I reopen it.

Just wondering if everyone is having the same issue and if there is a reason to use Xcode 10 instead of 9.

Comment: For new projects, same for me. Haven't tried setting it to v10.

Comment: Same for me. After selecting `Xcode 10.0` it resets back to `Latest Xcode (9.0)`.

Comment: Seems like a bug, since it thinks the Latest Xcode is 9.0 which is patently not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can verify the same behavior, but I wouldn't worry about it. All the setting is telling you is that it's possible to open the storyboard in Xcode 9. You can work with the storyboard in Xcode 10. I can't think of any reason why you would want to make it impossible to open the storyboard in Xcode 9.